# Search Builder is broken (Civi 5.4.0 / Drupal 7.59)

Tags: search-builder

Search Builder is broken : I don't have any "Select field", but only "Select Record Type" and "Operator" (sorry for the image in french) :

[image]

You can reproduce this bug on the demo configuration (civicrm.demo.civihosting.com, in 5.0.0), this way : Search Builder > Select "Individual", then go to Support > About CiviCRM, and then back : "Select Field" has disappeared : on my configuration, I have the same situation, but directly, without this forth and back operation.

Comment: best to compare with https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/builder?reset=1 i think as that will be running on latest code for certain

Comment: (to avoid reporting a bug that has already been fixed)

Comment: Thank you Pete : I did not know of this last version demo. Do you know if it is already fixed on 5.5.1 ? (BTW, if you change your comment to an answer, I will be glad to accept it)

Comment: if it works on dmaster and if it was a bug then yes i would say it has been fixed but haven't dug in to gitlab to look - https://lab.civicrm.org/groups/dev/-/issues?scope=all&utf8=%E2%9C%93&state=opened&search=search+builder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

best to compare with dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/contact/search/builder?reset=1 i think as that will be running on latest code for certain (to avoid reporting a bug that has already been fixed)